# Swift: Adding a subview to another subview

Tags: swift, view

I'm struggling in adding a subview to a view. The progress variable is set in its viewcontroller's `viewDidLoad()`. The progressView frame size is set correctly, it's just adding the subview that seems to go wrong. Any idea on what's missing?

```
class ProgressBar: UIView {
    var progressView = UIView()
    var progress: CGFloat? {
        didSet {
            setProgressBar(progress: progress!)
        }
    }

    func setProgressBar(progress: CGFloat) {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = true
        let progressViewWidth: CGFloat = self.frame.width * progress
        progressView.backgroundColor = .red
        progressView.frame = CGRect(origin: frame.origin,
                                    size: CGSize(width: progressViewWidth, height: frame.height))
        self.addSubview(progressView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
progressView.frame = CGRect(origin: frame.origin, size: CGSize(width: progressViewWidth, height: frame.height))
```

It should be replaced like

```
progressView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: CGSize(width: progressViewWidth, height: frame.height))
```

The position of progressView is related to progressBar's